# Error in db:migrate using JRuby on Rails with remote Amazon MySQL via SSL connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, rake, jruby

Error with jruby 1.7.19 (ruby 1.9.3 compatible on oracle JVM 1.8) but not error with the corresponding plan ruby 1.9.3 in “rake db:migrate" to modify MySQL of Amazon RDS via SSL connection.

I got a message below when “rake db:migrate” under jruby environment

```
“rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Access denied for user 'myid'@'ip_of_my_amazon_rds' (using password: YES)
arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:453:in `init_connection'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with –trace)”
```

No problem of “rake db:migarate” under the plan ruby.
No problem of “rake db:migrate” without SSL for both jruby and plain ruby.
I am wondering why I get the error with jruby via SSL connection.

My dabase.yml is

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  verifyServerCertificate: true
  useSSL: true
  requireSSL: true
  host: myhosturl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
  sslca: rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
  username: myid
  password: mypassword
  database: develop
```

Corresponding gems in Gemfile are

```
gem 'mysql2', platform: :ruby
gem 'jdbc-mysql', platform: :jruby
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', platform: :jruby
gem 'jruby-openssl', platform: :jruby
```

I can connect the same database by “rails dbconsole” commands under both jruby and ruby environments without error –  password is asked in both cases even it is specified in the database.yml file though.  I grabbed the rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem file from the Amazon web site and put it at the root of my app. I use rbenv to switch the environments.

I want to use Java libraries in my rails app with jruby.  If you have any idea to fix the problem, I greatly appreciate.

Comment: please share the versions of gems you mentioned are in the *Gemfile*

Comment: @kares I did not specify versions, but "bundle show" as for jruby * jruby-openssl (0.9.6), * jdbc-mysql (5.1.33), * activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.14), * jruby-openssl (0.9.6) -- as for ruby * mysql2 (0.3.18) –

Answer (score -1, accepted):

be sure to put the JDBC specific options under `properties:`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  host: myhosturl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
  sslca: rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
  username: myid
  password: mypassword
  database: develop
  properties:
    useSSL: true
    requireSSL: true
    verifyServerCertificate: true
```

still you might need to wrap the certificate (`sslca`) into Java's format, just read the [jdbc doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) how ... you do not need to manually set the properties - those can be specified on the command line or in `JRUBY_OPTS` e.g. `-J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/tomcat/etc/myKS.jks`

Comment: kares, the suggested configuration may solve the ssl problem, but I get new JDBCError as "rake aborted!  --- ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure --- The last packet successfully received from the server was 256 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 252 milliseconds ago.arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:453:in `init_connection' --- Tasks: TOP => db:migrate --- (See full trace by running task with --trace)".  There is no problem in "rails dbconsole" to access the database.

Comment: there is no error under plan ruby with the same suggested database.yml.  Once I google the message, there seems to be may reasons to have this error – I will keep updating my trials.